# Sieve of Eratosthenes returns large composite number (which is an error)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm implementing the Sieve of Eratosthenes in Python.  It returns composite numbers near the end of the search range:

```
def primes_Ero(n=1000):
    primes = []
    a = [True]*(n+1)
    a[0] = a[1] = False
    for (i,isprime) in enumerate(a):
        if isprime:
            for n in range(i*i,n+1, i):          
                a[n] = False
            primes.append(i)
    return primes
```

When using larger numbers, *n*, I end up with composite numbers.  I made a check to see which numbers are composite (compared to a brute force method),

Given *n*, what numbers are composite:

```
n= 100; []
n= 500; [493, 497]
n= 1000; [961, 989]
n= 10000; [9701, 9727, 9797, 9853, 9869, 9917, 9943, 9953, 9983, 9991, 9997]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the intention of `if i == 31:` ?

Comment: Also, you're using `n` for two different things.

Comment: @PaulHankin 's got it. Change the variable in the inner for loop, e.g.: `for k in range(i*i,n+1, i):` and the problem goes away.

Comment: I was using it to check for a different error.  i'll edit it to remove it

Comment: @jas that solves it! thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
 for n in range(i*i, n+1, i):
```

Initially `n` is set to the parameter value (default=1000) but after the for loop executes for the first time n will hold `i < n < i + n`. The second time the for loop is executed is faulty.

You should rename one of the `n`s that you're using. Consider giving it a proper name like `sieve_size` which is more descriptive of what it actually does.

One thing I would like to point out is, that while your code is clever you **are** modifying the list you're iterating over. This is generally considered bad practice.

Comment: Thank you for this!  I was putting together a few different ideas and forgot to rename the parts to something descriptive.  This helped a lot.

Comment: A comment on your last paragraph: There's no problem with modifying a value of a list by index while iterating over the list. It's only a problem if you're inserting or removing values from the middle of the list (since that changes the indexes of all of the later values).